# how to prevent currency from going back to default currency in shopify checkout?

Tags: shopify, currency

I have 2 currencies available in my shopify site. AED and USD. AED is the default currency. So if I choose USD in my site it converts all the product prices to USD perfectly, even until the cart. But when I click check out, it converts back to the default currency of AED.

Can anyone please help me out on this? I want to fix the chosen currency until the checkout site for my customers.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't. Shopify allows only one currency per store.

Currency converter is frontend informative tool only. When customers goes to checkout, currency chosen in store parameters is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very unfortunate but Truth that **Shopify Convert all currencies to store base(default) currency at checkout page.**

**Why This Happens:** Because in Shopify Normal plan your checkout page url is something like http://checkout.shopify.com/xxxxxx that specifies that your customer are using shopify checkout url.

**Solutions** :

- Switch to Shopify Plus Plan (Very Costly for small business)
- Implement some banner showing conversion rate and message on checkout and cart pages.
- Or Wait for something new to come with this feature that shopify promised years back.